# What is the cheapest hostel in the world?

Tags: budget, factoids, hostels

I'm asking about the cheapest bunk-bed or similar in a hostel in the world if only one traveller arrives to the hostel.

Comment: You might have to define a hostel, as there exist places that offer accomodation for free (e.g. shelters for homeless people), but are not open to anybody, particularly not to tourists.

Comment: The cheapest guest house I stayed in was cheaper than the cheapest hostel. Does it have to be a hostel?

Comment: Well, I'm asking about younth hostels only, it is, a place where travellers can spend a night in a bed for some money. I don't consider places that offers accomodation for free because these places are not tourism-oriented or require a friendship relationship (not just an economic transaction).

Comment: @ Peter Hahndorf - Me too, the cheapest was, I believe 50 rupees, which is just under one US dollar. It wasn't just one place but several which I can all list with corresponding prices (if needed). (EDIT: will change my comment to answer when I get some free time since these guest houses are cheaper then the one in Mark Mayo's answer.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well [one website did an investigation into this](http://www.priceoftravel.com/498/the-worlds-cheapest-hostel-us1-per-night/), and found:

[Garden Village Guesthouse in Siem Reap, Cambodia](http://www.gardenvillageguesthouse.com/)

Which has beds for **US$1 per night**.

To quote:

> But, there’s a catch…
>
> The $1 dorm beds are in a thatched-roof hut that is partially open to
>   the elements. It appears that you do get a mattress, pillow, towel,
>   and even a mosquito net, but that’s it. There’s also no proper locker
>   system out there so you have to leave your valuables at reception when
>   you are away.
>
> Nighttime average low temperatures are steady, ranging from 79F/26C in
>   March to 68F/20C in January, and it’s always humid, so it might not be
>   too comfortable on the warmest nights, but at least you’ll never be
>   cold.
>
> Also, the dorm beds are right next to the kitchen, so you need to be
>   prepared for some noise and smells while you are saving all that
>   money.
>
> On the other hand, the Garden Village offers:
>
> - Free pickup from the airport or bus terminal
> - Free (slow) Wi-Fi in the public areas
> - A volleyball court
> - Laundry service
> - Cheap bicycle rental
> - Affordable Khmer restaurant
> - Rooftop bar with cheap beer
>
> So you really do get most of the normal benefits of staying at a
>   hostel, even for this ridiculously low price. Want something better,
>   Mr. Moneybags?
>
> If you can afford US$6 per night you can get a “standard single” room
>   of your own, ranging up to a “deluxe triple” room for US$13.
>
> You can’t book the $1 dorms online, but you can book all the other
>   private rooms from their website. I’m told you can reserve the $1
>   dorms by emailing them, so you won’t have to just roll the dice and
>   hope one is open.
>
> Lest you think the Garden Village is just trying to get people stuck
>   in some remote place to sell them food and drinks, it is actually very
>   well located, only a few blocks from Pub Street and the main tourist
>   district of Siem Reap. Also, they have a good and cheap restaurant,
>   plus 50-cent Angkor draft beers available all day at their sunset
>   rooftop terrace.

Comment: There is no trace of "research" in this article, just a statement that you have to blindly accept.

Answer (score 17):

Cheapest I've come across anywhere in my travels was [Utopia Guesthouse](http://utopia-cambodia.com/) in Sihanookville, Cambodia. There you can stay in their dorm room for FREE (yup, costs nothing), or I think i paid $4 for a private room there.

Don't get much cheaper than that! it's a pretty fun place to stay too, if you're into the party-type vibe.

**Actually**, just looked them up, seems they charge $1 for a dorm bed these days.  Inflation huh.

Comment: So close! ;)  I bet there's some catch we can find for a free guesthouse / hostel *somewhere* :)

Comment: Inflation?!  Why, that's a bazillion percent!

Answer (score 7):

Many hotels in Japan, especially in large cities, will let you stay for JPY 1 (USD <0.01) under some conditions; typically if it's your birthday and you are over a certain age. For example [this one in Osaka](http://travel.rakuten.co.jp/HOTEL/158735/158735.html) if you are at least 70.